# Django not serving every static files when DEBUG=True

Tags: django

## Update

problem found, reason still unknown.

---

It is really weird that code works fine on Mac and PC with docker. But when i uploaded code to cloud server, it got 404 with some static files and 200 with the others.

```
bootstrap.min.css   200 stylesheet  (index) 119 KB  50 ms
dataTables.bootstrap.min.css    404 stylesheet  (index) 126 B   164 ms
buttons.bootstrap.min.css   404 stylesheet  (index) 126 B   165 ms
```

Here is my `settings.py`

```
...

DEBUG = True # still on develop

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

...
```

Maybe something wrong with `templates` or `host ip`:

## Templates

I put some basic css/js in `base.html`.
this `bootstrap` css works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% block head_meta %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    {% endblock head_meta %}

    <title>{% block head_title %}{% endblock head_title %}</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/static/vendors/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    {% block head_link %}
    <!-- HERE I PUT EXTENDED CSS/JS -->
    {% endblock head_link %}

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  ...
</html>
```

And i extend some css/js when i used in `some.html`.
these `Datatables` css/js got 404.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

    {% block head_title %}Search Results{% endblock head_title %}

    {% block head_link %}
    <!-- Datatables -->
    <link href="/static/vendors/Datatables-1.10.15/media/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="/static/vendors/Datatables-1.10.15/extensions/Buttons/css/buttons.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    {% endblock head_link %}
```

## Host ip

The only change, i suppose, between my Mac, PC with cloud server is host ip.

On Mac and PC, host ip is `localhost`.

On cloud server, host ip is a certain ip, like `1.1.1.1`.

## Thanks!

Django version: 1.11

Actually, on my PC and cloud server, i both used docker with ubuntu 16.04. So, there are in same env. And i used `python3 runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to test/debug my site. But they got different results as my question describes.

## Finally,

Sorry! I found my problem, it's really a `capitalisation problem` as @Alasdair says. But not with Mac and PC/Server. It occured with same docker containers (Ubuntu 16.04) on Windows and Ubuntu. I couldn't find it, because it works fine on Windows. And i still don't know why.

Thanks all!

Comment: do not use hardcoded links, instead type `{% load static %}` at the top of your template and then just call the given url like so: `href='{% static "css/your_file.css" %}'`

Comment: also it might be worth looking into the `collectstatic` command when you are deploying a project on a server, it does require adding some extra variables for the static files in your settings.py. [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/deployment/) here is a link explaining it in more detail

Comment: Make sure that you have the correct capitalisation. If the directory is `datatables-1.10.15`, then `Datatables-1.10.15` will work on a Mac, but not on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using nginx to reverse proxy for django app? Http requests for static files are independent of django requests, I suppose. If you didn't split two different requests, like:

```
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;

    uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;  

    uwsgi_read_timeout  1200;
    uwsgi_send_timeout  300;
    proxy_read_timeout  300;
}

location /static {
 alias /some-path/your_project/collected_static; 
}
```

your requests for static files would go through django,and then the paths of requests would not match your url patterns defined in urls.py, got 404 at the end.

Comment: I still use `runserver` for testing, not using any web server right now

Comment: What are the commands you executed on your pc and server ? Do they all work ?

Comment: Actually, on my PC and cloud server, i both used docker with ubuntu 16.04. So, there are in same env. And i used `python3 runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` to test/debug my site. But they got different results as my question describes.